# Update table from self table where value in the column is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table containing values:

```
dbid    name         userid
------------------------------
154     xyz          NULL
987     xyz          NULL
777     xyz          5
111     abc          NULL
745     abc          NULL
748     abc          6
```

expected output:

```
dbid     name     userid
------------------------------
154     xyz          5
987     xyz          5
777     xyz          5
111     abc          6
745     abc          6
748     abc          6
```

There are all null values in the userid column except one for one name. I want to set 5 in userid for all rows where name = 'xyz'.
Similarly, want to update the table to set 6 in userid where name = 'abc'.

What should be the query to update a table for the above scenario?

Note: Above is just an example. I have a table containing hundreds of thousands of records. I cannot write id 5 or 6 in the query.

Comment: Please don't use non-english words like "lakh" here. That will confuse people.

Comment: if your problem is solved - mark answer as accepted

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
update table_name 
   set table_name.userid = (
        select top(1) ss.userid 
          from table_name ss 
         where ss.name = table_name.name 
           and ss.userid is not null
        ) 
    where table_name.userid is null
```

This query is searching first record `userid` where name is the same and updating if `userid` is null

Comment: As you said there are many rows. if it is working slowly, just add index by name,

Answer (score 2):

You could update your table with a single UPDATE statement given the fact that the `name` idicates the `userid`. You can use the following query but if only such a unique dependence of those to attribute is present.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET name = (SELECT TOP 1 temp.userid FROM table_name temp WHERE temp.name = name)
WHERE userid is null;
```

Comment: also you should consider @Victor Ermakov answer, because the subquery should also contain `temp.userid is not null`

Answer (score 1):

Should I assume that columns dbid and name not null in the table defention? then also is the question the "output" do you want it as a result to a query, view or SP? Anyway simply put I would personly divid the table in to two tables.

table 1:

```
dbid     name  
---------------
154     xyz    
987     xyz    
777     xyz    
111     abc    
745     abc    
748     abc
```

table 2:

```
name     userid
------------------
xyz      5
abc      6
```

Then when i wanted the userid id for a specfic dbid I would simply:

```
SELECT A.dbid, A.name, B.userid FROM DATABASE.TABLE1 A INNER JOIN DATABASSE.TABLE2 B ON A.name = B.name
```

Which would result in output table:

```
dbid     name     userid
------------------------------
154     xyz          5
987     xyz          5
777     xyz          5
111     abc          6
745     abc          6
748     abc          6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [dbid] INT
   ,[name] SYSNAME
   ,[userid] SMALLINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([dbid], [name], [userid])
VALUES (154, 'xyz', NULL)
      ,(987, 'xyz', NULL)
      ,(777, 'xyz', 5)
      ,(111, 'abc', NULL)
      ,(745, 'abc', NULL)
      ,(748, 'abc', 6);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [dbid]
          ,[name]
          ,[userid]
          ,MIN([userID]) OVER (PARTITION BY [name]) AS [userid_precalc]
    FROM @DataSource
)
UPDATE DataSource
SET [userid] = [userid_precalc]
WHERE [userid] IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query

```
update table_name
set userid=(select top 1 T.userid from table_name T where T.name=table_name.name and T.userid is not null )
where userid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) Select your data into a **dummy table**.

```
SELECT * INTO dummy_tbl FROM myTable WHERE userid is not null
```

Query shall insert all data with UserID not null.

2) Execute your update command

```
update myTable set userid = (select userID from dummy_tbl where dummy_tbl.name  = myTable.name)
```

3) Remove your dummy table created.

```
drop table dummy_tbl
```

You are good to go, all userIDs has been updated accordingly.

BR, Moiyd

Answer (score 0):

use two update query

```
update table_name
set userid=5
where name = 'xyz';
update table_name
set userid=6
where name = 'abc';
```

Comment: It is just an example in the question. I have a table containing lakhs of records... I cannot write id 5 or 6 in the query. I need a query which updates lakhs records.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have lakh of record to update Table variable and window function should be avoided.

My idea is similar to @Moiyd.

First create non clustered indexon original table name column.if Useris not already Clustered index then,

```
Create Non Clustered index ix_myTable_name on myTable(name) include(userid)
```

if userid is CI then no need of

```
include(userid)
```

Store not null name and userid in separate table.

```
Create table dummy_tbl (name varchar(100),userid int)

Create Non Clustered index ix_dummy_name on dummy_tbl(name) include(userid)

insert into dummy_tbl (userid,name)
SELECT userid  FROM myTable WHERE userid is not null

update T 
set userid = T.userid
from myTable T
inner join dummy_tbl d on d.name  = T.name

Drop table dummy_tbl .
```

If possible permanently store value of dummy_tbl because that is the best and `normalise` way.you can store all `non repeating` column in `dummy_tbl`